# Android gradle build versionNameSuffix not found

Tags: android, gradle

I was trying to add build time as the suffix for the Develop flavor APK file. Here is my Gradle file setting.

```
def buildTime() {
    def df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'") 
    return df.format(new Date())
}

    productFlavors {
        develop {
            applicationId "com.myapp.develop"
            versionNameSuffix "-beta-build-${buildTime()}"
        }
    }
```

However I got the following messages saying the versionNameSuffix can not be found. I am using the latest Android Studio.What could be the problem? Thanks.

> Gradle DSL method not found: 'versionNameSuffix() The project  may be
>   using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.Open Gradle wrapper file
>
> The
>   build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.Apply Gradle plugin

Comment: AFAIK, `versionNameSuffix` is for `buildTypes`. For a `productFlavor`, you would set the `versionName` itself, just as you can in `defaultConfig`.